# Conditionally Remove Duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

So I have column A and column C. Both columns have duplicates. However I only want to delete based on the fact that there are duplicates if combined column A and column C have the same values.

Example:

```
Column A             Column B             Column C
Cool-1                 Def                  Story
Cool-1                 Def                  Story
Cool-1                 Def                  Movie
Cool-1                 Def                  Book
```

Cool-1 Def Story is essentially is the duplicate. How would I remove just those type of duplicates?

Comment: Welcome to SU!  While we can and will help you with trouble you may be experiencing creating a macro, we're not a macro-writing service.  Please include what you've tried/got already, and point out exactly where you're getting stuck.

Comment: There is no mention of macro writing other that the **VBA** tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this in Excel 2010 and it works. I used a filter. You can get more information about filters using this [link](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-d6549cf0-357a-4acf-9df5-ca507915b704)

Select the full table and click on data->Advanced(Sort & Filter). At the Advanced Filter window choose "Copy to another location". Select "Copy To" and put in a cell where you want the new data to copy to. Then select "Unique records only".

You will get a new table with all the records which are not duplicated

Answer (score 1):

As a VBA reference, all of the following statements will perform the task:

```
Sub removeDuplicates()

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange

        .removeDuplicates                           'duplicated rows based on all cols

        .removeDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)   'duplicates based on cols 1, 2, and 3

        .removeDuplicates Columns:=Array(3)         'duplicates in col 3

        .removeDuplicates Columns:=3                'duplicates in col 3

        .removeDuplicates Columns:=3, Header:=xlYes 'excludes header row

    End With

End Sub
```